# Flutter Android giving problem after update

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter is giving me a problem post the Flutter and Android update.

I had updated Flutter to Flutter 2 and also updated Android to 3.4. Now Flutter refuses to run the app in the Emulator. It throws a messy error message. I also tried migrating to AndroidX, but it's still not working. Then tried giving the build with old Android Studio but unfortunately, that too is not working. I am not able to give build for both Android and iOS, though Flutter Doctor passes all the test correctly. Error messages for Android and iOS is as below.

## For Android:

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

## For iOS

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error output from Xcode build:
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist:0: error: reading data: The file “GoogleService-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

How do I make this run in the Android and iOS emulators?

Comment: `"I had updated Flutter to Flutter 2 and also updated Android to 3.4"` - flutter version 2? what do you mean actually? the newest version in **dev** channel  is v1.7.11 imho (released 6/28/2019), also android 3.4... whatever it is - android version 3.* was released 8 years ago

Comment: My bad.. I mistakenly gave the Dart version, Flutter version : Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (9 weeks ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
Engine • revision 52c7a1e849
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

Comment: and you are trying to run some existing project or brand new one?

Comment: @pskink .. yes its an existing project, which was tested and deployed to the app stores .. and now when we opened the same project, the above errors were seen and the build is not happening.

Comment: so use a new project and try step by step adding your original dependencies - that way you will find what dependency breaks your build

Comment: @pskink, yes that option is there. I was wondering if we could resolve the above issues, then probably things would have been quicker and smooth.

Comment: @pskink .. yes, probably less than that, not a very complex app though, we are using Firebase for notifications and Google Maps, plus one API from an external CRM . Also once we troubleshoot this problem, the next big worry is to build a 64Bit release as per Google's latest Play Store Mandate.

Comment: If you don't have some third party libraries that are incompatibel with android X i would suggest following the instructions of https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility , and running "flutter clean" to delete any previous builds.